# How would I refer to an input element with an ID in JQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, button

For example,

`<input type="button" id="one" value="o" data-role="button" data-inline="true" class="game"/>`

I want to use it in a way that I can refer to the button's value through the ID, such as for changing the value's value.

How would I refer to this HTML button's ID without using `this.id` in JQuery Mobile?

Comment: T.J. Crowder has the answer, but you can get more information on all the selectors here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) (aka `jQuery()`) to look up the element, then (if you want to set the value) [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val):

```
$("#one").val(/* ...new value here...*/);
```

jQuery Mobile is built on jQuery core, so the core features are available.